# How do I go about auto expanding an entire webpage for scraping with pandas (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape html tables from https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/binance/ . On the page, there is a "load more" button. When this is clicked, more rows are displayed, but the URL doesn't change. When I pass this URL to pandas using `pd.read_html(url(`, it pulls the first 100 rows and nothing else. How do I auto load all the tables, either through the URL or through a command? Any help is appreciated.
Code:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import html5lib


url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/binance/"


df = pd.read_html(url)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
print(df)
```

Comment: If you're using this information to support financial decisions then you'd be well-advised to use an API rather than web-scraping a site.

Comment: I'm not, and I have already thoroughly explored several API's and they are unable to give me this information. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the URL does not change as all the results are loaded, they are just not displayed by default to save load time probably.
You most likely need to create a script which will keep clicking 'load more' whenever it appears and then run your scraper.

Comment: That makes sense. The only thing that confuses me is that I am not viewing the page as it is being scraped, I assume pandas is handling that on the back end.